# Display multiple values from Database in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create a report that will display different information from the database. In my report I need to display the column PieceType from the table job_pieces. But each company could have a different number of PieceTypes for example Company 135 only has type PLT but company 99 has PLT, CASE, CTN etc

In my report I want to display each PieceType like a column. Because if I just put `jp.PieceType` in the select then it will only display one value even though there could be 5 different pieces.
Like:

```
PieceType
CTN
```

But it should be like:

```
PieceType
CTN       CASE    PLT
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT  c.Name,
        jn.CompanyID,
        COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
        SUM(jn.ActualWeight) as GrossWt,
        (select COUNT(job_debriefs.ID) from job_debriefs WHERE JobID = jn.JobNo) as Debriefs,
        sum(jn.OutTurn) as Outturn,
        jp.PieceType
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN job_Address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

So you can see from the SQL query I have the columns Name, CompanyID, Jobs etc. I want the piece types to be displays in the row like a column to, so after Outturn it could be PLT, CASE etc depending on the company. I need to display all the PieceType values for each company but I won't know how many each company has. Right now my sql query only displays one PieceType

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jp.PieceType)`?

Comment: @jarlh so I need a GROUP BY for the piece types?

Comment: I haven't read the whole question, but I'd try GROUP BY c.Name, jn.CompanyID, jp.PieceType. Perhaps also jn.JobNo.

Comment: @user123456789: Okay, so I'll make this an answer, so future readers can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate function to make values from different rows a concatenated string in MySQL is GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT  c.Name,
        ...
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jp.PieceType)
FROM customer c
...
GROUP BY c.ID;
```

You can also specify the delimiter and an order by clause. More Information here: [dev.mysql.com/...function_group-concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).